Allure report customisation (npm version of allure)
I am using alloure (specifically the playwright allure version) - is there anyway I can customise the look of the allure report?
I have seen in some forums there are ways to override the java version, but those are very java-centric (and not always working it seems)
I am mostly looking at anyway of changing the colours and maybe the title of the report)
